# How to select column value as Comma Separated Values string in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having two table product and sale in sql database .

```
productId   name 
1           a
2           b
3           c

Sale 
ID  productId   sale
1      1        5
2      2        10
3      1        20
4      1        50
```

Now I want using of both table I need the out put in this format using sql :

```
productId   name    sale
1            a       5,20,50
2            b       10
```

can u plz any one tell me how i can get my sale column vale as comma separted values using sql query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a join between product and sales as below:

```
SELECT P.productId, P.name, GROUP_CONCAT(sale) AS 'sale'
FROM product AS P INNER JOIN sale AS S
ON S.productID=P.productID
GROUP BY P.productId;
```

See fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4581/3)

Comment: Nice example! I'll have to try fiddle on the next question I answer.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that proves that your query indeed works and an insurance for OP ;)

Comment: suppose  if i m using oracle then what is the right approach to getting the same out put can u plz guide me ...its only for just understanding i m asking

Comment: See [this](http://nimishgarg.blogspot.in/2010/02/oracle-new-string-aggregation.html) blog for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT if you are using MySQL:

```
SELECT P.productId, P.name, S.GROUP_CONCAT(sale)
FROM product AS P
LEFT JOIN sale AS S
ON S.productID=P.productID
GROUP BY P.productId;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: why use a `LEFT JOIN` here ?

Comment: LEFT JOIN is a more specified way of stating the join we are doing. An INNER JOIN will omit products that don't have any sales from the result.

Comment: By the way, because you specify `productID` in both tables by the same name, you can say USING (productID) instead of having to say ON S.productID=P.productID

Comment: Yeah I know about the ` using`  keyword, and I also know how the `left join` work but OP did not specify he want products that don't have any sale.

Comment: Right; one should always default to showing more information than less. If using an INNER join, the OP may not become aware that it is not showing all products even if they desired that, whereas with LEFT, the OP will become aware that it does show them, and can then change the behavior to suit their more specific requirements.

Comment: @Christopher :Thanks  for your answer.suppose if i m using oracle then what is the right approach to getting the same out put can u plz guide me ...its only for just understanding i m asking.

Comment: I think Almas' answer to that question (in the comments of his main answer) was perfect. The Oracle string aggregation functions (listagg or wm_concat) are the ticket.